# Timing in C with time.h

Tags: c, time, time.h

I am working on Ubuntu, and I want to time an assembler function in C.

Thats my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
extern void assembler_function(char*,int);

int main(){
   char *text1 = "input.txt";
   clock_t start=clock();
   sleep(3); // used for test
   //assembler_function(text1,0);
   clock_t stop=clock();

   //printf("%d %f\n",(int)stop,((float)stop)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
   printf("Time : %f \n",(double)start/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
   printf("Time : %f \n",(double)stop/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
   printf("Time : %f \n",(double)(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

   return 0;
}
```

The results are :

Time : 0.000000

Time : 0.000000

Time : 0.000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example, compiled on a Ubuntu box:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int64_t timestamp_now (void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
    return (int64_t) tv.tv_sec * CLOCKS_PER_SEC + tv.tv_usec;
}

double timestamp_to_seconds (int64_t timestamp)
{
    return timestamp / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int
main ()
{
    int64_t start = timestamp_now ();
    sleep (1);
    printf ("sleep(1) took %f seconds\n", 
            timestamp_to_seconds (timestamp_now () - start));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While correct, the lack of explanation limits the educational value. It is not clear _why_ this solution is better. It could be improved by identifying what the problem was (the lack of resolution in `clock`, as well as its functions suitability -- user-time versus wall-clock time) and how this resolves those problems.

Answer (score 1):

If `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is the typical value of `1000000`, it's entirely possible that the range you're measuring is less than one clock (1 microsecond).  Also, `sleep` will not contribute to increases in `clock` aside from the overhead of the call itself, since `clock` measures process time, not wall clock time.

Instead, try measuring the time taken to perform multiple calls to the assembler function, then dividing the results by the number of iterations.  If the total time to execute the assembler function is very small (e.g. 1ns) you'll need to be clever about how you do this, otherwise the overhead of the loop could end up being a significant part of the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

From the helpful `man`-page for `clock()`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The clock() function returns an **approximation of processor time used by the program**.
> ```

In other words, `clock()` is probably not what you want here, because you want to count elapsed wall-clock time, not CPU-usage time (note: `sleep()` uses almost no CPU time - it just sets an alarm for a wake-up time in the future and then, well, sleeps...).

Answer (score 0):

Use difftime:

First:

```
time_t t_ini;
t_ini=time(NULL);
```

At the end:

```
difftime((int)time(NULL), (int)t_ini);
```